# Python flask route: what does '?' mean in the end of rule?

Tags: python, flask

I have encountered the following piece of code in a flask project:

```
@app.route(r"^/subscriptions/?")
class SubscriptionsHandler:
    ...
```

I am not sure what the '?' symbol in the end of route pattern means?

I've checked docs and several tutorials but have not found similar route examples.

Comment: If it's a regular expression, it means that the last character, `/`, is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood mentioned, it means that the preceding character is optional. Specifically, it means /subscriptions and /subscriptions/ invoke the same route. You generally put it before methods, not before a class, though.